# Function to check if Input is in column in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, authentication

Okay, I'm creating an application which requires the user to input there Gamer-Tag during the registration process. Only 'Members' of a group may have access to the program and so I need the application to refuse anyone who's Gamer-Tag is **not** in the SQL Server database.

I adapted a function I created to log-in with your details and changed it to check if the Gamer-Tag is on the database, but I'm receiving a strange error:

> The column 'Gamer_Tag' is not a Member of 'Members_Details' Table.

Please note, that's an error and not what I am wanting it to do. It's saying the column 'Gamer_Tag' isn't in the table, but I know it is! I've checked spelling and spacing and everything's as it should be, so I'm assuming it's something wrong with the code.

The (relevant) register button code:

(Note, `RegUserName.Text` is the textbox that contains the users Gamer-Tag.

```
 Dim dbManager As New DatabaseManager()
    If dbManager.CheckGamerTagisMember(RegUserName.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Gamer-Tag Not A Member.")
        My.Settings.RegisterCount = 1
        My.Settings.Save()
        RegisterBTN.Enabled = True
        MsgBox("Registration Failed.")
        GoTo Ender
    Else
        MsgBox("Gamer-Tag is A Member.")
        GoTo Ender
    End If
```

And the function this is calling:

```
Public Function CheckGamerTagisMember(ByVal gamertag As String) As Boolean
    Connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source =" & My.Settings.ServerIP & ";Initial Catalog=Members_Details;Integrated Security=False;User=" & My.Settings.UserName & ";Password=********;")
    Connection.Open()
    Dim gamertagDatSet As New DataSet()
    usersDataAdapter.FillSchema(gamertagDatSet, SchemaType.Source, "Members_Details")
    usersDataAdapter.Fill(gamertagDatSet, "Members_Details")
    Dim table As DataTable = gamertagDatSet.Tables("Members_Details")

    For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim currentUsergt As String = table.Rows(i)("Gamer_Tag").ToString.Trim()
        If (currentUsergt = gamertag) Then
            gamertagDatSet.Dispose()
            Connection.Close()
            Return True
        End If
    Next

    gamertagDatSet.Dispose()
    Connection.Close()
    Return False
End Function
```

And to prove the column is in the table, here's the table's columns;

[image]

I'm new to structuring my code into classes, so I could be 'passing' things around wrongly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The connection string does not appear to be correct. It names the table, when it ought to name the database.

Comment: You may want to blank the password in your code example.  Also are you sure your application is connecting to the right server, and not a dev/test one that doesn't have the structure you expect?

Comment: Yeah, removed the password. The connection string is correct, it works on everything I've used it on.

Comment: LOL, You can't see the I.P Address or server name, so It's okay! :}

Comment: You named the database the same as the table?

Comment: And to clarify,the Members_Details table is in a Database called Members_Details.

Comment: ^That's never been an issue.

Comment: Attach SQL Profiler to your database and see if the call is being executed against it. The error you are getting sounds like either you are connecting to a different db, or the table columns listed in SSMS are out of date (right click and refresh the table definition).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't a clue what the issue is with your code (there's probably something else going on which is not evident in your question).

But I will say that the approach you are taking will not scale well. With each registration, you are downloading the *entire* table to the program and then scanning through the rows, one by one, looking for an ID.

It would be *much easier* to write a simple stored procedure to do this for you. You would also get the advantage of using indexes. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetMembers_ID
    @Gamer_Tag varchar(255) 
AS     
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT Members_ID
    FROM Members_Details
    WHERE Gamer_Tag = @Gamer_Tag
GO
```

You can call this stored proc this way:

```
Dim getMembers_IDCommand As New SqlCommand("TestProcedure", Connection)
getMembers_IDCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Dim gamerTagParam As SqlParameter = getMembers_IDCommand.Parameters.Add("@Gamer_Tag", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)

gamerTagParam.Value = gamertag 

SqlDataReader result = getMembers_IDCommand.ExecuteReader();
Dim exists As Boolean = myReader.Read()
result.Close()

Return exists
```

There, of course, *many* ways to execute a stored procedure and get the results. Several are [documented here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070). But the point is that a stored procedure is faster, more scalable and generally faster.

Comment: This will also address the case sensitivity problem with OP's code.